# C++ what is the correct way to access public static vector from another class?

Tags: c++

Considering following example:

```
//Source.cpp
#include <vector>
#include "MyHeader.h"

class A
{
public:
    static std::vector<B*> objects;
};

//MyHeader.h
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        A::objects.push_back(this);
    }
};
```

I want for each object of type B to be inserted in the vector in class A upon creation. Upon compilation I get the following errors:

```
Error   C2065    'objects': undeclared identifier   ...\MyHeader.h
Error   C2653    'A': is not a class or namespace name  ...\MyHeader.h
```

I am really not sure if this is because class B is in a separate file, or because I'm doing this in a completely wrong way. What is the correct way to access this vector from objects of type B?

Comment: You shouldn't try to use something declared in a .cpp file from a header.

Comment: Think about the order of yoru declarations, when you are using A::objects inside class B the A class is not yet defined, you should forward declare class B inside MyHeader, than define class A, than defnie class B using class A static member.

Comment: You need to move `class A` into a header file, either into MyHeader.h or into another header which MyHeader.h can then include. You also need to forward declare `class B` before `class A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem should look something like that:

```
//Source.cpp
#include <vector>
#include "MyHeader.h"

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        A::objects.push_back(this);
    }
};

//MyHeader.h
class B;
class A
{
public:
    static std::vector<B*> objects;
};
```

The idea is to declare the class A first, but since it neesd the pointer to class B which isn't defined we forward declare it with "class B", than we can use it as a pointer. Finally we include the MyHeader.h in cpp class to let class B know about the class A. In this way you can use it's static member.

Comment: Why can't I keep the order as it was, and instead add class A; before the definition of class B inside Myheader.h?

Comment: Because in case of using class B you are using pointer, so the compiler doesn't need to know the size and layout of the class. In your example you are using static method of a class so the compiler needs to know it exists, which means forward declaration isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

The `#include` preprocessor directive does a literal copy-paste of the code in the other file. So, while compiling and after the preprocessor stage, your code would look like this(you can actually see this output by compiling with the -E option in the compiler):

```
//Source.cpp

// whatever is in the vector.h file
class vector {
    // stuff
};

//MyHeader.h
class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        A::objects.push_back(this);
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    static std::vector<B*> objects;
};
```

So, in the B class constructor, A has not yet been defined, since to access a class, it must be defined before usage. So, if you want to access the `A` class from `MyHeader.h`, the best way to do it would just be to move class `A` into `MyHeader.h`, and make use of a forward-declaration of `class B`.

```
//Source.cpp
#include "MyHeader.h"
// main, other code

//MyHeader.h
#include <vector>

class B;

class A
{
public:
    static std::vector<B*> objects;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        A::objects.push_back(this);
    }
};
```

Making use of a forward-declaration of `class B` so that `A` knows that `B` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answers have been given already - that is forward declaration, a commonly used technique. I just want to point out that it will work only if you use a pointer to the forward declared type. The container (vector in your case) must know the size of the type.

```
class B;
class A
{
public:
    static std::vector<B*> objects; // size of B* is known - it is the size of a pointer
};

class B;
class A
{
public:
    static std::vector<B> objects; // size of B is unknown - an error
};
```